# How to correctly derivate quadratic cost function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, derivative, quadratic

Given the quadratic cost function `f(a) = 1/2 (a-y)^2`, I know that the derivative of the function with respect to `a` is `a - y`.
But I have no clue how to get there...
Can you provide me a link where this is explained easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Derivative in respect to what? Probably "a". Thus this is just about taking a derivative of a square of a difference.

```
f(a) = 1/2 (a-y)^2

df / da = d[ 1/2 (a-y)^2 ] / da
        = 1/2 d[ (a^2 -2ay + y^2) ] / da
        = 1/2 ( d[ a^2 ] / da - 2 d[ ay ] / da + d[ y^2 ] / da)
        = 1/2 ( 2a - 2y + 0 )
        = a - y
```

Comment: Thank you very much , was just smashing my head solving it by `(1/2)*2*d[(a-y)] = 1`